# Echo variable in a new line when using a loop?

Tags: php

I'm using a loop to echo User Names. How do I echo each user name in a new line?

I tried the following but no luck.

```
echo("\n".$userName);
```

and

```
echo($userName."\n");
```

Comment: Use `echo($userName."<br>");` or `echo $userName."<br>";` both will work. *Sidenote:* `\n` will return as a new line when writing to a file.

Comment: You can also do `echo($userName.PHP_EOL)`

Comment: if it did helped you, kindly mark the answer below as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question:

Use `echo($userName."<br>");` or `echo $userName."<br>";` both will work.

***Sidenote:*** Using `\n` will return as a new line when writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source of the page you will see that there is a new line separating them. HTML doesnt display a new line like that though so when parsed with your browser its removing the new line

Two main options are

```
<pre>
    <?php
    your_loop;
    ?>
</pre>
```

or inside the loop

```
echo($userName."<br>\n");
```

Which will add both a new line and a break line tag